# Optimize efficiency for all possible combinations of combinations

Tags: python

Let's say there is a tournament upcoming that you must help set up.

The tournament has N teams, given to you in a list such as:

```
teams = [Team1, Team2, ..., TeamN]
```

in each Team, there can be anywhere from 1-3 players that are each chosen from their own list of players.

Let's say each list represents possible Leaders, Rookies, Helpers.

Each team must have a Leader, but may have no potential Rookies or Helpers.

For example, Team1 may look like

```
Team1.Leaders = [Leader1, Leader2, ..., LeaderX1]
Team1.Rookies = [Rookie1, Rookie2, ..., RookieX2]
Team1.Helpers = [Helper1, Helper2, ..., HelperX3]
```

OR it may have an empty list for Rookies or Helpers, or both.

Each list of Teams, Leaders, Rookies, and Helpers may have varying sizes.

You must pick 1 Leader per team, and might pick 1 Rookie, or 1 Helper, or both depending on if Rookies and Helpers exist. (again, 1-3 players can be picked per team)

Get a list of combinations for all the ways you can pick players for each team.

For example,

```
Team1 = Team()

Team1.Leaders = [Leader1, Leader2]
Team1.Rookies = [Rookie1]
Team1.Helpers = []

Team2 = Team()
Team2.Leaders = [Leader3]
Team2.Rookies = []
Team2.Helpers = [Helper1, Helper2]

combinations = team_combinations(teams)
```

the expected output for combinations looks like:

```
[{"Team1":[Leader1, Rookie1], "Team2":[Leader3, Helper1]}, 
{"Team1":[Leader1, Rookie1], "Team2":[Leader3, Helper2]}, 
{"Team1":[Leader2, Rookie1], "Team2":[Leader3, Helper1]}, 
{"Team1":[Leader2, Rookie1], "Team2":[Leader3, Helper2]}]
```

where each dictionary is a combination of how you could have chosen players.

I am trying to make the process of getting combinations as fast as possible, as you can imagine when there are many players you can pick from, you may even have millions of different combinations.

I've tried using recursion, where the base case is len(teams) == 1, and the recursive step is anything else. I managed to create a function that works, but the process of getting combinations can even take an hour to complete.

What would be the fastest method of getting combinations? 
Would using itertools help?
Are there any faster methods?

Comment: What are the sizes of your inputs ? It might take a while as the complexity is quite huge.

Comment: Your plan of using `itertools` is a good one, it's done well for my team in the past. You're probably looking for `combinations` or `product`

Comment: For improving working code, go to [codereview.se]. You'll need to post your code to get meaningful advice. FWIW, if your output is in fact a list and not an iterator/generator, that's the first thing to work on. And yes using `itertools` is a good idea.

Comment: @BlueSheepToken each list of Teams, Leaders, Rookies, and Helpers may have varying sizes. There is no limit to how many teams, or players there are in each list

Comment: I am really sorry but "varying size" does not help me with the sizes. Generating combinations out of 4 lists with size n (which is basically your problem) is a `O(n^4)`algorithm. Which will take super long for a big `n`. So are you sure you need to generate all combinations ? What will it be used for ?

Comment: I made an analogy of my code because I did not want to post it publicly, but I am sure I want to generate all combinations. What I mean by varying sizes is that all 4 lists may have different sizes. nothing is concrete

Comment: I'll clarify: **only one** Leader per team can be picked? Or **[1-3]** Leaders? Your example illustrates only teams of 2 players, but we are able to pick [1-3] players per team - am I right?

Comment: only **one** leader, rookie, and helper per team can be picked. There will always exist a list of leaders, so you must always pick a leader. However, there may or may not exist a list of rookies or helpers.  and you are correct, in my example there are teams of 2 players

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, there is only one thing you can do to decrease complexity of your problem - decrease the number of teams and players. This is the one sure way to reliably accelerate your code.

On the other hand if total number of combinations is less than `10**9` any micro-optimization becomes significant. The use of low-level programming languages is also an option. As for Python, I would highlight the following points:

- using the built-in language features, such as in [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/itertools.html) module;
- using built-in `tuple` as a type for `leaders`, `rookies` and `helpers`. It has rather fast iterator and allowes to avoid implicit copying of data (e.g. in `itertools.product`);
- caching some combinations or team-combinations. The effectiveness of this optimization depends on the size of available memory and the number of small teams;
- stack instead of recursion. Despite the readability and ease of use, calling a function in Python is quit expensive pleasure. By using tail recursion, you run the risk of consuming all available memory and also go beyond the `sys.getrecursionlimit()`.
- python `for`-loop insted of stack;
- python functional features insted of `for`-loop.

Here it is a little sketch. All the classes I wrote are devoid of `__init__` and should be inherited with concrete realisations.

```
from itertools import product, chain
from operator import attrgetter
try:
    from math import prod # python 3.8
except ImportError:
    from functools import reduce
    from operator import mul
    prod = lambda i: reduce(mul, i, 1)


class Team(object):
    __slots__ = ('leaders', 'rookies', 'helpers')
    leaders: tuple
    rookies: tuple
    helpers: tuple

    def l_product(self):
        return product(self.leaders) # optimization tricky

    def l_r_product(self):
        return product(self.leaders, self.rookies)

    def l_h_product(self):
        return product(self.leaders, self.helpers)

    def l_r_h_product(self):
        return product(self.leaders, self.rookies, self.helpers)

    def __iter__(self):
        return chain(self.l_product(), self.l_r_product(), self.l_h_product(), self.l_r_h_product())

    def __len__(self):
        return (
            (l := len(self.leaders)) +
            (l * (r := len(self.rookies))) +
            (l * (h := len(self.helpers))) +
            (l * r * h)
        )

    @property
    def combs_size(self):
        # empiric value indicating quite close size of all produced tuples-combinations in memory
        return (
            (l := len(self.leaders)) +
            ((l * (r := len(self.rookies))) * 2) +
            ((l * (h := len(self.helpers))) * 2) +
            (l * r * h * 3)
        )


class CachedTeam(Team):
    __slots__ = Team.__slots__ + ('_cached_combs',)

    def __init__(self, team):
        self.leaders = team.leaders
        self.rookies = team.rookies
        self.helpers = team.helpers
        self._cached_combs = tuple(team)

    def __iter__(self):
        return iter(self._cached_combs)


class Tournament(object):
    _teams: list
    _producer: ... # Callable
    _free_memory = float('inf') # empiric value indicating ALL memory that can be occupied 
                                # while producing elements
    _max_effective_teams_length = 100 # empiric value, it is related with max-memory
                                      # that _compiled_producer can occupy
    _min_required_memory_multiplier = 4 # empiric value, it is related with memory required to
                                        # _stack_producer
    CachedTeam = CachedTeam
    _wrapper = tuple

    def __len__(self):
        return prod(map(len, self._teams))

    def __iter__(self):
        try:
            return self._producer()
        except AttributeError:
            self._create_producer()
            return self._producer()

    @property
    def teams_combs_size(self):
        return sum(map(attrgetter('combs_size'), self._teams))

    def _create_producer(self):
        teams = self._teams
        teams_length = len(teams)
        if not teams_length:
            self._producer = ((),).__iter__
        elif self.teams_combs_size < self._free_memory:
            # itertools.product creates tuple-copy for all non-tuple input
            self._producer = self._product_producer
        else:
            self._check_memory()
            self._configure_cache()
            if teams_length <= max(2, self._max_effective_teams_length):
                self._producer = self._compiled_producer
            else:
                self._producer = self._stack_producer

    def _product_producer(self):
        # it should be used when we have a lot of memory
        return product(*self._teams)

    @property
    def _compiled_producer(self):
        # e.g: ((t0,t1,t2,) for t0 in teams[0] for t1 in teams[1] for t2 in teams[2])
        # it should be used when number of teams is not big
        teams_length = len(self._teams)
        assert teams_length >= 1
        producer_code = 'lambda: (({yielded}){for_loops})'
        return eval(
            producer_code.format(
                yielded = ''.join(map('t{},'.format, range(0, teams_length))),
                for_loops = ''.join(map(' for t{0} in teams[{0}]'.format,
                                        range(0, teams_length))),
            ),
            {'teams': self._teams}
        )

    def _stack_producer(self):
        # it should be used when number of teams is big
        wrapper = self._wrapper
        teams = self._teams
        teams_length = len(teams)
        assert teams_length >= 2
        common = [None] * teams_length # common memory
        teams_iterators = [None] * teams_length
        teams_iterators[0] = iter(teams[0])
        last_team = teams[-1]
        x = 0  # stack pointer
        max_x = teams_length - 1
        pre_max_x = max_x - 1

        while True:
            try:
                common[x] = next(teams_iterators[x])
            # except StopIteration:
            except:
                if x: # if first place loop is not over:
                    x -= 1 # decrement stack pointer
                    continue
                return
            if x == pre_max_x:
                for common[max_x] in last_team:
                    yield wrapper(common) # don't forget to use wrapper that creates copy!!
            else:
                # create next place loop and increment stack pointer
                teams_iterators[x] = iter(teams[(x := x + 1)])

    def _check_memory(self):
        self._free_memory -= (len(self._teams) * self._min_required_memory_multiplier)
        if self._free_memory < 0:
            raise ValueError('not enough memory to operate with teams')

    def _configure_cache(self):
        teams = self._teams
        CachedTeam = self.CachedTeam
        free_memory = self._free_memory

        # We want to cache small teams at first. It is also quite easy to get their iterators,
        # so we want to iterate them more often than not-cached teams:
        teams.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
        try:
            for i, t in enumerate(reversed(self._teams), 1):
                if (cs := t.combs_size) > free_memory:
                    return
                teams[-i] = CachedTeam(t)
                free_memory -= cs
        finally:
            self._free_memory = free_memory
```

I've wrote three basic implementations of getting cartesian product of all teams: `_product_producer`, `_compiled_producer` and `_stack_producer`. To select one of them we need to know approximate value of memory we have. That's why we need to declare `combs_size`, `_free_memory`, `_max_effective_teams_length`, `_min_required_memory_multiplier`, `teams_combs_size`.

The inner `_teams` should be private because the order of produced combinations depends on order of teams. With a view to optimize producers we may want to resort teams.

`_configure_cache` can be called somewhere inside `__init__` but it seems wrong to me because initialization should not be long. You can also throw it away if you want.

Here some tests:

```
team0 = Team()
team0.leaders = ('L00',)
team0.rookies = ('R00', 'R01', 'R02')
team0.helpers = ('H00', 'H01')

team1 = Team()
team1.leaders = ('L10', 'L11')
team1.rookies = ()
team1.helpers = ()

team2 = Team()
team2.leaders = ('L20',)
team2.rookies = ()
team2.helpers = ('H20', 'H21')

team3 = Team()
team3.leaders = ('L30',)
team3.rookies = ('R30', 'R31', 'R32', 'R33', 'R34')
team3.helpers = ()

tm0 = Tournament()
tm0._teams = [team0, team1, team2, team3]

tm1 = Tournament()
tm1._teams = list(tm0._teams)
tm1._free_memory = 30

tm2 = Tournament()
tm2._teams = list(tm0._teams)
tm2._free_memory = 30
tm2._max_effective_teams_length = 3
```

.

```
>>> list(team2)
[('L20',), ('L20', 'H20'), ('L20', 'H21')]

>>> for t in tm0._teams:
...     print(len(list(t)), len(t), type(t))
12 12 <class '__main__.Team'>
2 2 <class '__main__.Team'>
3 3 <class '__main__.Team'>
6 6 <class '__main__.Team'>

>>> len(tm0) == len(list(tm0)) == len(list(tm1)) == len(list(tm2)) == 12 * 2 * 3 * 6 == 432
True

>>> for t in tm1._teams:
...     print(len(t), type(t))
12 <class '__main__.Team'>
6 <class '__main__.Team'>
3 <class '__main__.CachedTeam'>
2 <class '__main__.CachedTeam'>

>>> list(tm0._product_producer()) == list(tm0._compiled_producer()) == list(tm0._stack_producer())
True
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it really helps out a lot. also, i'd like to ask, is it possible to remove combinations if they fail a certain condition while the combinations are being produced? wouldn't that also help with efficiency? for example, let's say leader1 has a conflict with any of the members in the entire combination, then remove that combination

Comment: Any reduction in the number of possible **produced combinations** should significantly increase productivity. This means that methods based on filtering inappropriate combinations are not suitable - in fact, they only add complexity. On the other hand, you can calculate the filtered chunk once and cache it. Another way is to initially create only filtered combinations. You can apply this approach in case when `leader1` have conflict with his team members. If he has confict with members of other teams in current combination, caching may be the better.

Comment: Also, you can sort the order of teams any way you like, so you can separate producing combinations of teams_without_conflicts and combinations of conflict_teams.